# Creating Java Packages in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been using Eclipse for a while and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on with my first project in IntelliJ.  I've read the documentation, and searched other questions, but I still can't seem to grasp it.  I think there is something wrong with my project structure.  This is what my structure currently looks like;

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure]

I'm trying to run the `JavaForLoop` class, but whenever I do, compilation fails because I have errors in the `StringMethods` class of the `strings` package.  My question is why would that prevent compilation if the two classes are in separate packages?  Neither class uses the other, and they both have the appropriate `package` declaration statements.  With a similar structure in Eclipse, this would work.  Should I be using a different project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IDEA adds Build Configuration which is executed before launch and includes following steps (taken from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/build-process.html)):

- Compiling source code in the source path of a module and placing results to the output path.
- Compiling source code in the test path of a module and placing results to the test output path.
- Creating copies of the resource files in the output path.
- Reporting problems in the Messages tool window.

[image]

check if it's your case in Edit Configuration screen and if so, remove it.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks.  So by default, all the files in all the modules of the project are being compiled?

Answer (score 0):

To use a class from a different package you must declare a import statement to the class.

In your JavaForLoop.java add the import before the class statement (and after package declaration where its the case)

```
//package ...
import strings.StringMethods;
//public class JavaForLoop { and the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Intellij uses regular javac, which will fail to compile if you have errors anywhere in the code.

Eclipse has it's own compiler, that allows to compile and even run code that has compilation errors, causing a runtime exception if any part of the code that has errors is run.  This allows you to run parts of the code that work even if other pieces of code are failing.

The simple solution is to resolve your compilation errors.  You can also use the eclipse compiler with Intellij, but I've never done this so I can't comment on how well it works.